# Outdated - CS50's Introduction to Programming with Python: Code does not break

Tags: python, cs50

I'm using the CS50's tutorials to teach myself python. I am trying to solve the 'Outdated' problem in problem set 3. The code works when I input date as 9/8/1636(i.e., correctly transforms date to yyyy-mm-dd and outputs the result) but not when I input September 8, 1636; it again prompts me for input. I cannot figure out where I went wrong.

The context to the problem can be found [here](https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/3/outdated/), and the code i tried is copied below:

```
# Initiate the list
month_li = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
]

# Start infinite loop that breaks when a valid date is entered
while True:
    # Prompt the user for a date (format: 9/8/1636 or september 8, 1636)
    input_date = input("Date (in month/day/year order): ").strip()

    # Attempt to transform date into yyyy-mm-dd format
    try:
        # Split month, day and year by "/" separator and convert to integer
        month, day, year = map(int, input_date.split("/"))

        # Check whether month and day fall within expected ranges
        if 1 <= month <= 12 and 1 <= day <= 31:
            # If so, then print year, month, and date
            print(year,f"{month:02}",f"{day:02}", sep = "-")

            # Break out of the loop
            break

        else:
            # Check if date string starts not with a number but a letter
            if not input_date[0].isdigit():
                # Split the date by space
                month, day, year = input_date.split(" ")

                # A comma (,) will remain, so need to get rid of that
                day = day.replace(',', '')

                # Convert day and year to integers; will deal with month after
                day = int(day)
                year = int(year)

                # Capitalize month for case insensitivity
                month = month.capitalize()

                # Need to check if the month exists in the list
                if month in month_li and (1 <= day <= 31):
                    print(year,f"{month_li.index(month) + 1:02}", f"{day:02}", sep = "-")
                    break

    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Don't do `except: pass` unless you are so confident your code will not hit any unforeseen exceptions that you're willing to spend a lot of time scratching your head saying "what happened?" when it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at what happens.  When you enter that string, the `map(int...` is going to throw an exception.  That will skip to your `except`, which does nothing and loops around to ask for input again.  You never get past the that statement.

What you SHOULD do is throw out the try/except, and move the `if not input_date[0].isdigit()` to the front.  That way, you don't TRY to parse bad data.

```
while True:
    input_date = input("Date (in month/day/year order): ").strip()
    if not input_date[0].isdigit():
        # Split the date by space
        month, day, year = input_date.split(" ")
        ...
    else:
        # Split month, day and year by "/" separator and convert to integer
        month, day, year = map(int, input_date.split("/"))
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I don't really understand why you think the if else code blocks should be switched. but it's working now after I also removed the try/except.

Comment: The KEY is that you need to check for a digit BEFORE you try to call `int`.  That's the reason I flipped the blocks.  You could have solved the problem by moving the `except` immediately after the `map(int...` line, but it's not good practice to use exceptions to replace data validation.

Answer (score 0):

create `month_list` = [...]

- infinity loop with `while True`
- inside loop:

```
   try:
...
   except(EOFError, KeyboardInterrupt):
      print("")
      break
   except:
      pass
```

- inside `try`:

```
    x = input("Date: ").strip()
      if not x[0].isdigit():
         m, d, y = x.split(" ")
         if not d.endswith(','): # <--- repromt if d not endswith `,`
            continue
         d = d.replace(',', '')
         d = int(d)
         y = int(y)
         m = m.capitalize()
         if m in a and (1 <= d <= 31):
            print(y, f'{month_list.index(m)+1:02}',f'{d:02}', sep="-")
            break
      else:
         m, d, y = map(int, x.split("/"))
         if 1 <= m <= 12 and 1 <= d <= 31:
            print(y, f'{m:02}',f'{d:02}', sep="-")
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the same problem with this solution.

```
while True:
    date = input("Date: ").strip()
    try:
        if "/" in date and date[0].isnumeric():
            m, d, y = map(lambda x: int(x), date.split("/"))
        else:
            raise ValueError

        if 1 < m > 12 or 1 < d > 31:
            continue
        else:
            print(f"{y}-{m:02}-{d:02}")

    except ValueError:
        if "," in date and not date[0].isnumeric():
            m, d, y = date.split(" ")
            m = month_list.index(m) + 1
            d = int(d.replace(",", ""))
        else:
            continue

        if 1 < m > 12 or 1 < d > 31:
            continue
        else:
            print(f"{y}-{m:02}-{d:02}")
```